# Self nested infinite dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a self nested infinite dictionary of the form

```
a = {'a': 'a'}
a.update({'b': a})
```

It works pretty well and values by key `'b'` may be retrieved numerous times:

```
a['b']['b']['b']['b']
```

Q1: Is there a limit on depth of key `'b'`?

Q2: What is the memory size of this object?

Comment: The object is a two-entry dictionary that holds the string `'a'` and a reference to itself. So, the size is very modest. The number of `['b']`'s is limited by your interpreter.

Comment: There's no limit, because the `dict` itself is not infinite, only self-referential. `a['b'] is a` will be `True`. (There may be a *syntactic* limit on how large an expression you can write, but that's not related to the `dict` itself.)

Answer (score 1):

As DYZ mentioned, since the update is only referencing `a`, the size is small.

```
import sys
a = {'a': 'a'}
id(a)                 # 2420845831296
a.update({'b': a})
id(a['b'])            # 2420845831296
sys.getsizeof(a)      # 232 bytes
```

For the limit, check this question: [Can python list and dictionary be nested infinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224094/can-python-list-and-dictionary-be-nested-infinitely)

Comment: It is true that `id(a) = id(a['b'])`. The size 232 bytes is incorrect, I guess. The size of dict cannot be derived by simple `sys.getsizeof(a)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760 However, the exact object size is not very important here. It is important to know that the size is relatively small. Thanks.